# Perl: How to replace only matched part of string?

Tags: regex, string, perl

I have a string `foo_bar_not_needed_string_part_123`. Now in this string I want to remove `not_needed_string_part` only when `foo_` is followed by `bar`.

I used the below regex:

```
my $str = "foo_bar_not_needed_string_part_123";

say $str if $str =~ s/foo_(?=bar)bar_(.*?)_\d+//;
```

But it removed the whole string and just prints a newline.

So, what I need is to remove only the matched (.*?) part. So, that the output is

```
foo_bar__123.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's another way, and it's quite simple:

```
my $str = "foo_bar_not_needed_string_part_123";
$str =~ s/(?<=foo_bar_)\D+//gi;
print $str;
```

The trick is to use lookbehind check anchor, and replace all non-digit symbols that follow this *anchor* (not a symbol). Basically, with this pattern you match only the symbols you need to be removed, hence no need for capturing groups.

As a sidenote, in the original regex `(?=bar)bar` construct is redundant. The first part (lookahead) will match only if some position is followed by 'bar' - but that's exactly what's checked with non-lookahead part of the pattern.

Comment: Nice, way to get this done. Thanks, for the redundant part info.

Comment: Can you clarify one thing is `look-behind/look-ahead` capturing or non-capturing. For:eq `st=foobar` and I use `foo(?=bar)` it will not capture `bar` in `$1` unless I use `foo(?=bar)(bar)` than I have `bar` in `$1`. So, is there any way I can make them capturing.

Comment: The construct `(?=%pattern%)%pattern%` is redundant by definition: it's the same as (`[a-c]|a|b|c`), for example. In both cases you check for the same pattern twice. If you need to capture the part that follows `foo`, just use `foo(bar)` syntax without any lookahead checks: it will match only if `foo` is followed by `bar`.

Comment: @Noob: If you want to capture the value in look-ahead you can do `foo(?=(bar))`. Although the example you presented is redundant.

Comment: @raina77ow: this doesn't strictly match the requirement, as the OP said he wanted to retain the underscore before the trailing digits

Comment: @Borodin That would be quite easy to fix (the easiest is just to change `...\D+//gi` to `...\D+/_/gi`). But I thought it was actually an artifact of the code given in the question, and not the real intent. )

Answer (score 6):

You can capture the parts you do not want to remove:

```
my $str = "foo_bar_not_needed_string_part_123";
$str =~ s/(foo_bar_).*?(_\d+)/$1$2/;
print $str;
```

Comment: This sort of thing has long been superseded by look-ahead / look-behind

Comment: @Borodin, yes and no. Lookbehind has some serious limitations (e.g. many regex flavors, including those used by Perl and Python, only allow fixed-length strings) and I'm glad that tanguy mentioned this too.

Answer (score 2):

What's about to divide string to 3 parts, and delete only middle?

```
$str =~ s/(foo_(?=bar)bar_)(.*?)(_\d+)/$1$3/;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
my $str = "foo_bar_not_needed_string_part_123";

say $str if $str =~ s/(foo_(?=bar)bar_).*?(_\d+)/$1$2/;
```

Outputs:

> foo_bar__123

PS: I am new to `perl/regex` so I am interested if there exist a way to directly replace the matched part. What I have done is captured everything which is required and than replaced the whole string with it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
(?<=foo_bar_).*(?=_\d)
```

In this variant, it includes in result ALL (`.*`) between `foo_bar_` and `_"any digit"`.

In your regex, it includes in result:

```
foo_
```

Then it looks for "bar" after "foo_":

```
(?=bar)
```

But it DOES NOT included at this step. It is included on the next step:

```
bar_
```

And then rest of line is included by `(.*?)_\d+`.

So, in general: it includes in result all this that you typed, EXCEPT (?=bar), which is just looking for "bar" after expression.

Comment: I can't comment not mine post, but anyway:

foo(?=bar)(bar) has no sense, since it looks for "bar" after "foo" (but DOES NOT includes it, just looking, if "bar" is here, then "foo" included in result, if "bar" is absent, then "foo" does not included), and then includes bar.

foo(bar) should works fine, "bar" will be in $1.

Answer (score 1):

go with

```
echo "foo_bar_not_needed_string_part_123" | perl -pe 's/(?<=foo_bar_)[^\d]+//'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use look-behind/look-ahead in this case

```
$str =~ s/(?<=foo_bar_).*?(?=_\d+)//;
```

and the look-behind can be replace with `\K` (keep) to make it a little tidier

```
$str =~ s/foo_bar_\K.*?(?=_\d+)//;
```